# Can $((a,b), \lor, \land)$ be a boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Can I construct Boolean algebra for an open interval $(a, b)$? If I cannot, then why? (I know about $[0, a]$ interval. It constructs with max and min)

Comment: Boolean algebra like structure - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)
I tried to do this with max and min. For example x or y = Max(x,y), xy = Min(x,y), not x = a+b - x, 0 = a, 1 = b. But a and b are not in $(a, b)$

Comment: I didn't even bother to wiki it, I feel silly now

Comment: There are boolean algebras equinumerous with $(a,b)$, so...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Let $f$ be a bijection from $[0,a]$ onto $(a,b)$. Define $x\lor_{(a,b)}y$ as $f^{-1}(x)\lor _{[0,a]}f^{-1}(y)$, for all $x$ and $y$ in $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really possible to get a good answer to your question without a more specific definition. Here's the specious answer: There exists a function $f:(a,b) \to [0,1]$ so that the range of $f$ is all of $[0,1]$ and no two members of $(a,b)$ are sent to the same point. Fix some Boolean algebra on $[0,1]$, and construct a Boolean algebra on $(a,b)$ as follows: $a \wedge b = f(a) \wedge f(b)$, $a \vee b = f(a) \vee f(b)$. The maximum element will be $f^{-1}(1)$, and the minimum element will be $f^{-1}(0)$.

This answer is probably not very satisfying for you. What I think you wanted to ask was something along the lines of "is there a natural way to construct a Boolean algebra on $(a,b)$" or "is there a way to construct a Boolean algebra on $(a,b)$ so that the operations are familiar functions". But without a formal definition of "natural" or "familiar", there is no good answer to either of those questions.

Comment: I think the only natural way to interpret *natural* as you mean it is for the boolean algebra to preserve the standard order.

Comment: @GitGud In which case the answer would have to be "no", because there isn't a maximum or minimum element.